# rolling back a deployment on heroku then uploading another version without roll forward?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I rolled back my app on heroku from v7 to v4 (for example) which is a previous version from a week ago. Since v7 introduced some errors, I want to upload a completely new version. I tried to deploy this new version on heroku but got this error

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:boiling-bastion-xxxx.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Since I don't want anything to do with v7 and want to upload this new version instead, do I still run `git push`? I don't want to roll forward as the latest version (v7) introduced some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use,

```
git push heroku master -f
```

Comment: what does it do? I did `git push heroku master` without the -f but I got the error message posted above.

Comment: `git push -f` is used for forced push. it forces the new version no matter what version is on heroku

Comment: can I do a rollback after doing a forced push? I just found out that the code that I just force pushed causes the same error. Rollback doesn't appear to be working

Comment: then correct the errors and force push again.. also check the server log for more details that causing error.

Comment: you can use heroku rollback

Comment: never ever do just `git push -f`.  Since you didn't specify a branch, git is going to overwrite every branch, including master.  If any of your branches aren't up to date, you just overwrote any changes you don't have locally.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to git force push up to heroku to change releases.  The correct way to is do it is: `heroku releases:rollback [RELEASE]`

`heroku releases` will list out what deploys you've done in case you don't know what deploy is what release.